# Issue with Nginx, http authentication and dynamic IP address

Tags: nginx, authentication, nat, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

I am trying to get Nginx as a **reverse proxy to authenticate users performing inbound http requests.**

My ISP provides me with a **dynamic IP**. I am not sure how to configure my ADSL router (NAT rules).

I also want Nginx **to listen to port 80 and redirect to 8080 (tomcat).**

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Main website Tomcat instance
    upstream tomcat {
        server  127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
    auth_basic_user_file /home/julien/system/temp/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  92.128.100.110;

        location / {
            # Proxy all the requests to Tomcat
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Authorization ""; #$http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `default` configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name 92.128.100.110;

    auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
    auth_basic_user_file /home/julien/system/temp/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

***The http authentication is not performed. I am not sure what is wrong with my config. Can anyone please help?***

Comment: Check out catch all server block at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html . That should solve at least one issue you described!

Comment: And don't host a web server at home.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: :-) It is just for showing a webapp to friends of mine...

Answer (score 0):

<sub>< bot >convert self-answerer question to CW< /bot ></sub>

I was finally able to get it working [thanks to Pothi](https://serverfault.com/questions/545530/issue-with-nginx-http-authentication-and-dynamic-ip-address#comment629279_545530). Here is my final config `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  _;
        proxy_set_header Authorization ""; #$http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
        auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
        auth_basic_user_file /home/julien/system/temp/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth

        location / {
            # Proxy all the requests to Tomcat
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        }
    }
```

Nat rule:

- in port: 80
- out port: 80

And don't forget to open port 80 on ufw firewall.